# IBM DB2 Warehouse Developer Edition web console error when connecting to LDAP server

Tags: db2, db2-luw, dashdb

Current DB2 Warehouse Dev Ed Docker image, Windows 10 Docker Desktop     10.09.2, Docker run command appears successful, try to connect to webconsole   at localhost:8443.  Browser sits there "waiting for localhost" after many   minutes get an error message: "An error occurred while connecting to your   LDAP server. Please verify that the server is available and that console is    configured to use LDAP."  I also get the same error using a Docker Desktop on a Mac.

Using v3.6.0-db2wh_devc-linux Docker image pulled this morning.

On the Windows 10 laptop Docker is configured with 24gb, 6cpus and 4gb swap
On the Mac, Docker is configured with 12gb, 6cpus, 4gb swap.

Here's the Docker run command I'm using for both Windows & Mac

```
    docker run -itd -p 8443:8443 -p 50000-50001:50000-50001 --net=db2wh_net   --privileged=true --name=Db2wh -v db2wh_vol:/mnt/bludata0 -v db2wh_vol:/mnt  /blumeta0 store/ibmcorp/db2wh_ce:v3.6.0-db2wh_devc-linux
```

```
    PS C:\Users\StephenKimmel\IBMCloud> docker start Db2wh
    Db2wh
    PS C:\Users\StephenKimmel\IBMCloud> docker logs --follow Db2wh
    Failed to insert module 'autofs4'
    systemd 219 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR         +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN)
    Detected virtualization docker.
    Detected architecture x86-64.

    Welcome to Db2 Warehouse!

    Set hostname to <cb20b07a55ce>.
    Cannot add dependency job for unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer, ignoring:   Unit is masked.
    [  OK  ] Reached target Timers.
    [  OK  ] Reached target Paths.
    [  OK  ] Reached target Swap.
    [  OK  ] Reached target Local File Systems.
    [  OK  ] Created slice Root Slice.
    [  OK  ] Created slice System Slice.
    [  OK  ] Listening on Delayed Shutdown Socket.
    [  OK  ] Reached target Slices.
    [  OK  ] Listening on Journal Socket.
           Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
           Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
           Starting Journal Service...
    [  OK  ] Started Create Volatile Files and Directories.
    [ INFO ] Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown is not active.
    [DEPEND] Dependency failed for Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
    Job systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service/start failed with result    'dependency'.
    [  OK  ] Started Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
    [  OK  ] Started Journal Service.
    [  OK  ] Reached target System Initialization.
    [  OK  ] Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
    [  OK  ] Reached target Sockets.
    [  OK  ] Reached target Basic System.
         Starting System Security Services Daemon...
         Starting SASL authentication daemon....
         Starting LSB: Bring up/down networking...
   [  OK  ] Started SASL authentication daemon..
   [FAILED] Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking.
   See 'systemctl status network.service' for details.
   [  OK  ] Reached target Network.
   [  OK  ] Reached target Network is Online.
         Starting System Logging Service...
         Starting LSB: Supports the direct execution of binary formats....
   [  OK  ] Started System Logging Service.
   [  OK  ] Started LSB: Supports the direct execution of binary formats..
   [  OK  ] Started System Security Services Daemon.
   [  OK  ] Reached target Multi-User System.
          Starting SystemD Unit file to manage nping echo-server as a  service...
   [  OK  ] Reached target User and Group Name Lookups.
   [  OK  ] Started SystemD Unit file to manage nping echo-server as a service.
    [  OK  ] Started The entrypoint script for initializing the service.
    [ 5863.056359] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Running 'Cgroup filesystem mount existence' test...
    [ 5867.627520] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Running 'Platform sanity' test...
    [ 5867.728488] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Running 'Docker storage driver'   test...
   [ 5867.736446] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Running 'SELinux status' test...
   [ 5867.826912] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Running 'Root volume total-space' test...
   [ 5868.231104] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: IBM Db2 Warehouse configuration: SMP
   [ 5868.313257] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Successfully set timezone to UTC
   [ 5868.554978] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Unable to discover the domain from static hostname.
   [ 5887.715775] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Checking if the initialization has been done previously ...
   [ 5887.728377] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: #################################################
   [ 5887.731566] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: The IBM Db2 Warehouse stack is already initialized.
   [ 5887.734585] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Checking if the container needs to be upgraded to a new version ...
   [ 5887.737636] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: #################################################
   [ 5889.286614] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: The container needs to be re-linked to v3.6.0.
   [ 5892.845232] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: configure_user_management completed successfully.
   [ 5898.845279] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Updating the IBM Db2 Warehouse container on node dockervmguest ...
   [ 5900.790669] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Recovering license key ...
   [ 5901.994449] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: #################################################
   [ 5901.994812] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Starting the services in the container
   [ 5901.994961] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: #################################################
   [ 5903.976602] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: #######################################################################
   [ 5903.976888] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: ###   Starting all the services in the IBM Db2 Warehouse stack      ###
    [ 5903.977209] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: #######################################################################
   [ 5903.977518] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: * If this is a new deployment, the stack is initialized, which might
   [ 5903.977776] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: take a while.
   [ 5903.978037] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: * If this is a container update, it might take a while to start the services,
   [ 5903.978312] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: depending on whether an engine or database update is required.
   [ 5904.193634] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Checking if database server engine needs to be upgraded/migrated ...
    [ 5904.505763] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: **************** IBM Db2 Warehouse license information ****************
    [ 5904.508864] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: * License type             : Unwarranted
    [ 5904.512067] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: * License expiry date      : Permanent
    [ 5904.514919] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: * License status           : Active
    [ 5904.517783] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: ***********************************************************************
    [ 5907.660932] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: configure_user_management completed successfully.
    [ 5913.449297] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Restart LDAP/LDAP-depended network services AND set OS to use LDAP Authentication ...
    [ 5920.823850] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: database SSL configuration
    [ 5925.760682] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Updating spark properties file
    [ 5961.806118] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Current  total memory:  23542 MB
    [ 5961.809050] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Previous total memory:  3928 MB
    [ 5961.815300] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Current number of maximum database partitions per node : 1
    [ 5961.818020] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Previous number of maximum database partitions per node: 1
    [ 5961.824736] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Current instance memory : 80
    [ 5961.827359] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Previous instance memory : 80
    [ 5962.004973] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Spark support is going to be disabled.
    [ 5962.010608] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Spark support was previously disabled.
    [ 5962.013283] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Memory configuration has changed.
    [ 5962.143504] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: IBM Db2 Warehouse instance will use up to 80% of the total memory.
    [ 5975.161154] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Running AUTOCONFIGURE to tune the database ...
    [ 5983.708930] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Spark support is disabled.
[ 5985.295307] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Update and set IBM Db2 Warehouse Cfgs
    [ 5996.383193] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Updating DSM configuration after container update ...
    [ 5996.463478] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: SERVER STATUS: INACTIVE
    [ 6018.321160] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Updating database transaction log settings ...
    [ 6040.566146] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Run hardware inventory collection
    [ 6137.269296] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: [2019-05-09.16:36:34]  INFO: Starting Db2 instance
    [ 6138.950563] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: [2019-05-09.16:36:36]  INFO: Activating Database bludb
    [ 6146.308239] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: SERVER STATUS: INACTIVE
    [ 6148.477150] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Setting file permission for cleanup and updating dswebserver.properties...
    [ 6149.768853] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: sed: can't read /etc/sssd/sssd.conf: Permission denied
    [ 6149.834877] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Failed to stop sssd.service: Interactive authentication required.
    [ 6149.839671] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: See system logs and 'systemctl  status sssd.service' for details.
    [ 6149.843289] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: rm: cannot remove ‘/var/run/sssd.pid’: Permission denied
    [ 6149.858392] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Failed to start sssd.service: Interactive authentication required.
    [ 6149.861351] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: See system logs and 'systemctl status sssd.service' for details.
    [ 6149.864454] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Starting dsserver...
    [ 6150.194394] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Starting server dsweb.
    [ 6207.202682] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Server dsweb started with process ID 15502.
    [ 6207.243376] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Started dsserver successfully.
    [ 6268.472171] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Running the Health check ...
    [ 6268.475281] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: #######################################################################
    [ 6268.478363] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: ##      --- IBM Db2 Warehouse stack service status summary ---       ##
    [ 6268.481433] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: #######################################################################
    [ 6271.032424] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status slapd.service
    [ 6271.032671] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: SUMMARY
    [ 6271.032865] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Db2TablesOnline               : RUNNING
    [ 6271.033153] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Db2connectivity               : RUNNING
    [ 6271.033356] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Db2running                    : RUNNING
    [ 6271.033588] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: LDAPrunning                   : RUNNING
    [ 6271.033833] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: WebConsole                    : RUNNING
    [ 6271.219900] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Backing-up the system configuration ...
    [ 6271.228858] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: System configuration backed-up to /mnt/blumeta0/SystemConfig/dockervmguest on the named volume successfully
    [ 6272.959180] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: *****************************************************************************   ***
    [ 6272.962892] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: ******          Successfully started IBM Db2 Warehouse           ******
    [ 6272.966971] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]:   ********************************************************************************
    [ 6272.970780] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: *
    [ 6272.974264] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: * Next steps:
     [ 6272.977368] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: *
    [ 6272.981321] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: * 1. If you were monitoring the container startup progress using docker logs
    [ 6272.985007] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: command, use Ctrl+c key-sequence to detach from the Docker logs console.
    [ 6272.989729] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: * 3. Log in to the web console using the following information:
    [ 6272.993079] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: *        URL: https://localhost:8443
    [ 6272.996271] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: *        Default user ID    : bluadmin
    [ 6272.999939] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: * 4. If you forgot the bluadmin password, reset it
    [ 6273.004204] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: *        by running "docker exec -it Db2wh setpass <new password>".
    [ 6273.007621] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: *        For other user management, use the web console.
    [ 6273.010741] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: * 5. After you have confirmed that IBM Db2 Warehouse was successfully upgraded and
    [ 6273.013828] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: *         started, remove any old containers and images.
    [ 6273.117142] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: * Note: Db2wh is an example of a container name. Use the container name
    [ 6273.117496] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: that you specified for the docker run command.
    [ 6273.121236] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: *
    [ 6273.125072] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: ********************************************************************************
    [ 6273.137114] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Created symlink from   /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/crond.service to /usr/lib/systemd/system/crond.service.
    [ 6273.235829] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Saving deployment logs...
    [ 6274.595803] start_dashDB_local.sh[69]: Logs saved successfully
```

I've increased the memory and cpus allocated to Docker as above.
I can connect to the container and run DB2 commands manually, connecting    to the bludb and listing tablespaces (for instance.)

I'm using the default bluadmin password on the Mac but have reset the one on the Windows PC using the Docker setpass command.

I can issue an ldapsearch command which appears to connect to the LDAP server successfully.  Not clear if the output below indicates there are no entries in the LDAP server or not.

```
    [root@dockervmguest - Db2wh /]# ldapsearch -x -Z
    # extended LDIF
    #
    # LDAPv3
    # base <DC=BU19,DC=SSO,DC=AD,DC=ISOPS,DC=IBM,DC=COM> (default) with scope  subtree
    # filter: (objectclass=*)
    # requesting: ALL
    #

    # search result
    search: 3
    result: 32 No such object

    # numResponses: 1
```

Expected result is to see the DB2 Warehouse web console in the browser.

Comment: This question is not about programming so it may be better suited to dba.stackexchange.com .  Apart from that, the docker image works correctly for me in Linux (ubuntu 16.04). Can you verify your host operating system has an entry in its hosts file for its hostname and it's real IP-address?  It's unclear if your host is using a dynamic IP-address. The `docker logs --follow Db2wh` in my case tells me to open https://<ipaddress>:8443/console (i.e. not localhost) , and I'm using a static IP4-address.

Comment: @mustaccio.  Thanks.  Having read that localhost in a Docker host can confuse traffic (see the IBM Cloud Private install instructions,) I commented out localhost in the Windows hosts file and assigned the PC's IP address a hostname.  No change.  I have a co-worker who can install V3.5.0 on a Mac with no issues and his log file shows localhost:8443 as well.  However, I think a network routing issue is high on the suspect list.  The fact that I get the same hang on a Mac and a Windows 10 PC on same network (using 192.168.0.0) - wondering what's the common element if not the network.

Comment: I also am looking at the page source of the "Sign-in DB2 Warehouse" page thinking perhaps that's trying to make a direct call to the LDAP server in the container however I don't see any listener in the Windows network on port 389 where I do see a listener on that port inside the container.

Comment: If you have a working Mac and a failing Mac (or a working+failing Win10) then you can compare them to find clues. docker exec into the container to bash and compare the slapd.log files (may be in /var/log ) and the system message log (e.g. /var/log/messages or whatever is the MachOS equivalent). Also compare the Db2wh_local.log files to see where they are substantially different.

Comment: Apparently the DB2 Warehouse developer edition web console web page directly accesses the LDAP server in the container.  I added a "-p 389:389" parameter to the Docker Run command so the LDAP server inside the container would be exposed outside the container and I am now able to bring up the web console logging in with the bluadmin id.  

docker run -itd -p 8443:8443 -p 50000-50001:50000-50001 -p 389:389 --net=db2wh_net --hostname db2wh1 --privileged=true --name=Db2wh -v db2wh_vol:/mnt/bludata0 -v db2wh_vol:/mnt/blumeta0 store/ibmcorp/db2wh_ce:v3.5.0-db2wh_devc-linux

Comment: I'd be curious to know if anyone with a working version (without this additional -p parameter for LDAP,) can see port 389 listening in a netstat -a -n on their host operating systems(Mac or Linux or even Windows.)  I'll post a comment referencing these two comments as the answer in a day.   Thanks everyone who responded.

Comment: My host has slapd listening on 389 for tcp local 0.0.0.0:389 and foreign 0.0.0.0:* , and slapd is also listening on tcp6 for :::389  and :::*.    There are two established connections between slapd and sssd_be.  I don't need to map port 389 for the Db2 warehouse console to operate.

Comment: @Mao, I also see a listener on 0.0.0.0:389 (as well as 0.0.0.0:8443 and 50000 and 50001) but I think those are exposed by Docker networking.  if you do an ifconfig or ipconfig to see your network interfaces do you see a virtual ethernet adapter, possibly labeled DockerNAT?  On Win10 with Docker Desktop that's what I see.  that has an IP address of 10.0.75.1.  Docker network inspect db2wh_net shows the actual DB2 Wh container is listening on 172.18.0.1.  I believe the -p parameters in the run cmd are used to tell Docker which ports to map into to the host network from the private nets.

Comment: Docker Desktop may behave differently from Docker CE or Enterprise in how it exposes ports but I don't have any recent experience with either of those.  Anyway, I think I'm going to declare victory with this problem since I have a way to get the web console to work which was the original issue.    I'll add a product review on Docker Hub (don't see any other way to report the issue.)

Answer (score 0):

When using Docker Desktop on Windows 10 apparently you need to explicitly identify, using the -p parameter, the TCP/IP ports exposed outside the container.  The Web Console needs direct access to the LDAP server (slapd) running in the container to authenticate the userid and password.  I had to add -p 389:389 to the Docker run command to cause the Docker Desktop network to start listening on that port on the host machine and to (map? bridge? NAT? route? proxy?) connections from the Web Console to slapd in the DB2 Warehouse DE container. This may not be needed when running Docker Enterprise(or even CE) on a Linux or Windows server, ymmmv.

```
docker run -itd -p 8443:8443 -p 50000-50001:50000-50001 -p 389:389 --net=db2wh_net --hostname db2wh1 --privileged=true --name=Db2wh -v db2wh_vol:/mnt/bludata0 -v db2wh_vol:/mnt/blumeta0 store/ibmcorp/db2wh_ce:v3.5.0-db2wh_devc-linux
```

Comment: The IBM documentation page already mentions the remapping of port 389. But that detail was omitted from the summary pages at docker store for some reason.  The address is here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/admin/deploy_winmac_using_linux.html